# Creating a MySQL cluster, using mysql-server docker containers, on multiple servers

Tags: mysql, docker, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

I'm trying to create an MySQL cluster of 3 nodes using [mysql-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/) docker containers.

I have **3 separate cloud instances** and docker is setup on all 3 of them. **Each server will have only 1 container running on it** - to achieve High Availability when in cluster.

I start the containers on all 3 servers, individually, with the command

```
docker run --name=db -p 3301:3306 -v db:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql/mysql-server
```

I'm mapping the port 3306 of container to my **server's 3301 port**. I've also created a new user 'clusteradmin' for remote access.

Next, from mysql-shell, I ran following command - for all 3 servers

```
dba.configureInstance('clusteradmin@serverIp:3301')
```

I get similar message for all-
[image]

**Note** that it says 'This instance reports its own address as 39xxxxxxxxxx:3306'.

Next I create a cluster in one of the server successfully. But, when adding the other 2 servers to this cluster, I'm getting the following error

[image]

On checking the logs for that particular server, I see the following lines

[image]

It says 'peer address a9yyyyyyyyyy:33061 is not valid'. This is because, since the containers are running on different servers, the container-id is not recognised by other containers on other server.

I tried many options but to no avail. One method was to use *report-host* and *report-port* options when starting the container, like so

```
docker run --name=db2 -p 3301:3306 -v db2:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql/mysql-server --report-host=139.59.11.215 --report-port=3301
```

But, the issue with this approch is that, during dba.configureInstance(), it wants to update the port to default value and throws error like so

[image]

Anybody who has managed to create such a cluster of mysql-server containers running on different servers, I would really appreciate pointers in this regard.

Comment: Are you using NDB Cluster, InnoDB Cluster, or some other Cluster?

Comment: I'm using InnoDB cluster

Answer (score 0):

I have gone over the documentation and source code but have not found an explanation why listening and advertising different ports is problematic.

I have solved the problem by using `--port 3301` when invoking mysql-server:

```
docker run --name=db2 -p 3301:3301 -v db2:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql/mysql-server --report-host=139.59.11.215 --port 3301
```