# How to change default port of mysql-server docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to run *mysql/mysql-server* image in 3 different containers on the same host (End goal is to have innodb cluster running on the host for demo project). And instead of using bridge network and port mapping, I want the containers to start in host network mode.

But, since all 3 containers will be running on same host, I can't have more than one container using same host port.

This is the docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    network_mode: "host"
```

Is it possible to modify docker compose file to achieve my objective? Any pointers would be really helpful!

Comment: Did you check expose/ports docker-compose rules?

Comment: yes, but ports is ignored with host network mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `--port=3305` in the `command`.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    network_mode: "host"
    command: --port=3305
```

Comment: thanks! command: --port helped. One more doubt - if the container has 2 services running (ex. mysql on 3306 and mysql-shell on 33060) - how to change ports for both the services? Also, please have a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837078/creating-a-mysql-cluster-using-mysql-server-docker-containers-on-multiple-serv

Answer (score 1):

Host networking is almost never necessary and it disables some core Docker features, like port remapping.  If you remove the `network_mode: host` setting you can pick which host port is used without changing the underlying image at all.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    ports:
      # You pick the first (host) port.
      # Second port is the port the container process uses,
      # and is usually fixed per image.
      - '3305:3306'
```

Host networking also disables normal inter-container communication as described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  Unless you're specifically trying to manage the host's network or you have a truly large number of ports you're listening to (like thousands) you should use the default ("bridge") networking.  The only downside is that other containers won't be on the host name `localhost`, but that should just be a matter of providing appropriate configuration to your service.

Comment: I tried with bridge network initially, but had trouble setting up InnoDB cluster with that. If possible, please also have a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837078/creating-a-mysql-cluster-using-mysql-server-docker-containers-on-multiple-serv